# Tectia SSH Logon via CMD with password as argument

Tags: authentication, ssh, sftp

hello I'm trying out Tectia 6.4 via cmd but I'm having trouble login in with password as argument. I always get the error "too many argument" 
I tried

```
sftpg3.exe host password
sftpg3.exe host --password=password
sftpg3.exe host -p password
```

If i just enter host-name i get the prompt for the password in order to login. there no way to use password as argument in order to log in via cmd? I look into help and they have option for password but it does not seems to be working for me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
sftp3.exe --password=yourpassword  username@host
```

Make sure your options are first and you are including your `username@host` in the command also.

optional `-B file.txt` where `file.txt` includes your FTP command to execute after connecting.

NOTE: Having your password in cleartext is considered a security risk.

Comment: I actually used wrong exe sftp3.exe does not have a -P as argument however sshg3.exe does! I took me a while to figure it out so using sshg3.exe -p = pass hostname let you log in. thank you for the help